# Is there a standard set in java that can take a comparator for equality checks but iterates in insertion order?

Tags: java, set

I have a set of objects which I cannot modify by overriding their equals or hashCode functions (which don't behave as I would like), but for which I do have a comparator that behaves as I would like.  Is there a Set I could use that leverages the comparator to not allow duplicates, but when iterated iterates over insertion order?

Essentially I am looking for a cross between the TreeSet and LinkedHashSet.  Something like a LinkedTreeSet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered creating a class that wraps the objects and implements an equals/hashCode function that behaves as you expect? A bit of a hassle but you seem to have heavy constraints.

Also, if you do end up doing this or finding something more suitable, make sure to comment it properly, or the next guy will make the wrong assumptions about equals/hashCode methods!

PS: a TreeSet still uses equals to [rule out duplicates](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#add%28E%29)

Comment: I think this is an error in the javadoc of add, because the class documentation says: "a TreeSet instance performs all element comparisons using its compareTo (or compare) method, so two elements that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the set, equal".

Comment: This is actually my current solution--and it works--however I am wondering if there a data structure that wouldn't necessitate the wrapper class.

Comment: Darn. You're right. Looked into the code, then write a test program just in case. Never found a base-java javadoc error before...

Comment: Reported a bug to oracle... let's see how that goes.

Answer (score 0):

`TreeSet` doesn't do what you want, either. It doesn't use the comparator to determine duplicates; it only uses it to preserve a sort order. From the [Set docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html):

> A collection that contains no duplicate elements. More formally, sets contain no pair of elements e1 and e2 such that e1.equals(e2), and at most one null element.

In particular, in the [TreeSet docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#add(E)):

> public boolean **add**(E e)
>
> Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present. More formally, adds the specified element e to this set if the set contains no element e2 such that (e==null ? e2==null : e.equals(e2)). If this set already contains the element, the call leaves the set unchanged and returns false.

I don't think there's any way around the fact that the `Set` will use the `.equals()` method of the objects in it. You will have to extend the class and override the `.equals()` method, or make a class that contains the objects you want to put in the set, as [Miquel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8406112/15055) suggested.

Comment: I think this is an error in the javadoc of add, because the class documentation says: "a TreeSet instance performs all element comparisons using its compareTo (or compare) method, so two elements that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the set, equal".

Answer (score 0):

Apache's [commons-collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/) has a [ListOrderedSet](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/set/ListOrderedSet.html).  It sounds like what you want.

> Decorates another Set to ensure that the order of addition is retained
>   and used by the iterator.

But this will NOT use the comparator to check for duplicates...